# CSS can not style borders between radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I wonder whats the best solution for this task. I have 4 radios and I want to have flexible lines between them.
[image]

Comment: show us your code better in snippet

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 5):

When using radio buttons in this way you should remember to use a `fieldset` and a `legend` to provide semantic meaning to your radios for accessibility. (I have included `.sr-only` class from bootstrap to hide the `legend` and `inputs`)

Below is an example of radios with the line behind them all, let me know if something isn't clear.

Fieldset:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

sr-only: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/accessibility/#visually-hidden-content

```css
/* used to visually hide elements but keep keyboard and screen reader functionality */
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}

/* reset default fieldset styles */
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* rating container */
.rating {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

/* pseudo element used to create the line behind circles */
.rating::before {
  background: #ddd;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* style labels as circles */
.rating__label {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #ddd;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

/* selected circle styles */
input:checked + .rating__label {
  background: #e18083;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend class="sr-only">Rating</legend>
  <div class="rating"> 
    <input id="one" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="sr-only">
    <label for="one" class="rating__label">1</label>

    <input id="two" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="sr-only">
    <label for="two" class="rating__label">2</label>

    <input id="three" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="sr-only">
    <label for="three" class="rating__label">3</label>

    <input id="four" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="sr-only">
    <label for="four" class="rating__label">4</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You should explain, or at least comment in your code, what is providing the line. To the less experienced it will not be obvious that `.rating::before` is the line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use just one line behind all four of your circles.

If you need some space between a circle and adjacent lines you can just add `border: 2px solid #fff` to the circles.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.process-steps-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.ps-process-step {
    display: flex;
}
.col3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}
.ps-process-step .col3:not(:first-child):before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 48%;
    left: -50%;
    right: 0;
    border: 2px #ECECEC solid;
}
.process-step-num {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.process-step-circle {
    border: 5px #ebebeb solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #ECECEC;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #5d5353;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    z-index: 1;
}
.process-steps-wrap .col3:nth-child(3) .process-step-circle {
    background-color: #E18183;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="process-steps-wrap">
  <div class="row ps-process-step">
    <div class="col3 ">
      <div class="process-step-num">
        <div class="process-step-circle step1">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3 ">
      <div class="process-step-num">
        <div class="process-step-circle step2">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="process-step-num">
        <div class="process-step-circle step3">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="process-step-num">
        <div class="process-step-circle step4">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the above code.

Comment: This one looks better than my designers work :D :D :D but product owners doesn't want surprises -_-

Comment: That seems like a *lot* of unnecessary `divs` . You should also indicate what is providing the line, `.ps-process-step .col3:not(:first-child):before` is not obvious and burred in a lot of other CSS. A good answer provides an explanation, as well as code.